# How do I make a relationship between my Aspnetusers table and a custom table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have extended my `Aspnetusers` table to include `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `StudentID`.

I want a simple registation page where in the admin will create student accounts. The student accounts then should 
be able to add their own personal contact details.

Now, I created a custom table named `"ContactDetails"` containing the ff:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string StudentContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mother First Name")]
    public string MotherFirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mother Middle Name")]
    public string MotherMiddleName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mother Last Name")]
    public string MotherLastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mother Contact Number")]
    public string MotherContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Father First Name")]
    public string FatherFirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Father Middle Name")]
    public string FatherMiddleName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Father Last Name")]
    public string FatherLastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Father Contact Number")]
    public string FatherContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Emergency First Name")]
    public string EmergencyFirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Middle Name")]
    public string EmergencyMiddleName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Last Name")]
    public string EmergencyLastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Contact Number")]
    public string EmergencyContactNumber { get; set; }


    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

**IdentityModels class:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string College { get; set; }

    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Contact> ContactInfo { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {

        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }


}
```

How do I put my user`(Aspnetusers.Id)` in ContactDetails `(User_Id)` table when the student is registered? 
How do I make a relationship between them?

**My AdminController:**

```
 // GET: /Admin/Edit/Create 
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    #region public ActionResult Create()
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ExpandedUserDTO objExpandedUserDTO = new ExpandedUserDTO();

        ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();

        return View(objExpandedUserDTO);
    }
    #endregion

    // PUT: /Admin/Create
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    #region 
    public ActionResult Create(ExpandedUserDTO paramExpandedUserDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            if (paramExpandedUserDTO == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var Email = paramExpandedUserDTO.Email.Trim();
            var UserName = paramExpandedUserDTO.Email.Trim();
            var Password = paramExpandedUserDTO.Password.Trim();
            //
            var FirstName = paramExpandedUserDTO.FirstName.Trim();
            var MiddleName = paramExpandedUserDTO.MiddleName.Trim();
            var LastName = paramExpandedUserDTO.LastName.Trim();
            var StudentID = paramExpandedUserDTO.StudentID.Trim();
            var College = paramExpandedUserDTO.College.Trim();


            // UserName is LowerCase of the Email
            UserName = Email.ToLower();

            // Create user

            var objNewAdminUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = UserName, Email = Email, FirstName = FirstName, MiddleName = MiddleName, LastName = LastName, StudentID = StudentID, College = College };             


            var AdminUserCreateResult = UserManager.Create(objNewAdminUser, Password);

            if (AdminUserCreateResult.Succeeded == true)
            {
                string strNewRole = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Roles"]);

                if (strNewRole != "0")
                {
                    // Put user in role
                    UserManager.AddToRole(objNewAdminUser.Id, strNewRole);
                }

                return Redirect("~/Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: User "+Email+ " already exists!");
                    //"Error: Failed to create the user. Check password requirements.");

                return View(paramExpandedUserDTO);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();
            //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: " + ex);
            return View("Create");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Im not sure how do I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `Contact` class you should have these:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

In `ApplicationUser` class you should have these:

```
public int ContactId { get; set; }
public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
```

Comment: any idea on how to do this, if the contact class is in a separate ClassLibrary